# Get same day of same week

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment JS and I would like to get the same day of the same week last year.

We're on our third week of the month, a Monday. Third week because the first week started Sunday `01/03/2020`. And in that week, we had only one day in the month matching.

I want to get the third week, the Monday of last year.

I tried doing this but it's returning `04/03/2019` rather than `11/03/2019`. Any idea how can I fix this? And also why does my code have that behavior?

```js
console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'years').day(moment().day()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first find what day of year it *currently is* then subtract a year and add the days back in:

```js
const currentDay = moment().dayOfYear()
const thisDayLastYear = moment()
  .subtract(1, 'year')     // go back one year
  .startOf('year')         // start at the beginning
  .add(currentDay, 'days') // add the days back in
  .format('DD/MM/YYYY')

console.log(thisDayLastYear)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using year in the subtraction use 52 weeks instead :

Edit :

```
console.log(moment().subtract(52, 'weeks').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

you can try it with different dates such as :

```
moment("20200311","YYYYMMDD").subtract(52, 'weeks').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```